下記のソースコードをmacOSで起動させたいが、方法がわかりません
import "dotenv/config";
import { graphDataTestRunner } from "~/utils/runner";
import { groqAgent, shiftAgent, nestedAgent, openAIAgent, stringTemplateAgent, propertyFilterAgent, textInputAgent } from "@/experimental_agents";

const system_interviewer =
  "You are a professional interviewer. It is your job to dig into the personality of the person, making some tough questions. In order to engage the audience, ask questions one by one, and respond to the answer before moving to the next topic.";

const graph_data = {
  version: 0.3,
  nodes: {
    name: {
      agent: "textInputAgent",
      params: {
        message: "インタビューしたい人の名前を入力してください:",
      },
    },
    context: {
      agent: "stringTemplateAgent",
      params: {
        template: {
          person0: {
            name: "Interviewer",
            system: system_interviewer,
          },
          person1: {
            name: "${0}",
            system: "You are ${0}.",
            greeting: "Hi, I'm ${0}",
          },
        },
      },
      inputs: [":name"],
    },
    messages: {
      agent: "propertyFilterAgent",
      params: {
        inject: [
          {
            index: 0,
            propId: "content",
            from: 1,
          },
          {
            index: 1,
            propId: "content",
            from: 2,
          },
        ],
      },
      inputs: [[{ role: "system" }, { role: "user" }], ":context.person0.system", ":context.person1.greeting"],
    },

    chat: {
      agent: "nestedAgent",
      inputs: [":messages", ":context"],
      params: {
        namedInputs: ["messages", "context"],
      },
      isResult: true,
      graph: {
        loop: {
          count: 6,
        },
        nodes: {
          messages: {
            // This node holds the conversation, array of messages.
            value: [], // to be filled with inputs[2]
            update: ":swappedMessages",
            isResult: true,
          },
          context: {
            value: {}, // te be mfilled with inputs[1]
            update: ":swappedContext",
          },
          groq: {
            // This node sends those messages to Llama3 on groq to get the answer.
            agent: "openAIAgent",
            //agent: "groqAgent",
            params: {
              //model: "Llama3-8b-8192",
              model: "gpt-4o",
            },
            inputs: [undefined, ":messages"],
          },
          translate: {
            // This node sends those messages to Llama3 on groq to get the answer.
            agent: "openAIAgent",
            params: {
              system: "この文章を日本語に訳して。意訳でも良いので、出来るだけ自然に相手に敬意を払う言葉遣いで。余計なことは書かずに、翻訳の結果だけ返して。",
              model: "gpt-4o",
            },
            inputs: [":messages.$last.content"],
          },
          output: {
            // This node displays the responce to the user.
            agent: "stringTemplateAgent",
            params: {
              template: "\x1b[32m${1}:\x1b[0m ${0}\n",
            },
            console: {
              after: true,
            },
            inputs: [":translate.choices.$0.message.content", ":context.person1.name"],
          },
          reducer: {
            // This node append the responce to the messages.
            agent: "pushAgent",
            inputs: [":messages", ":groq.choices.$0.message"],
          },
          swappedContext: {
            agent: "propertyFilterAgent",
            params: {
              swap: {
                person0: "person1",
              },
            },
            inputs: [":context"],
            isResult: true,
          },
          swappedMessages: {
            agent: "propertyFilterAgent",
            params: {
              inject: [
                {
                  propId: "content",
                  index: 0,
                  from: 1,
                },
              ],
              alter: {
                role: {
                  assistant: "user",
                  user: "assistant",
                },
              },
            },
            inputs: [":reducer", ":swappedContext.person0.system"],
            isResult: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    translate: {
      // This node sends those messages to Llama3 on groq to get the answer.
      agent: "openAIAgent",
      params: {
        system: "この文章を日本語に訳して。出来るだけ自然な口語に。余計なことは書かずに、翻訳の結果だけ返して。",
      },
      inputs: [":chat.swappedMessages.$last.content"],
    },
    output: {
      // This node displays the responce to the user.
      agent: "stringTemplateAgent",
      params: {
        template: "\x1b[32m${1}:\x1b[0m ${0}\n",
      },
      console: {
        after: true,
      },
      inputs: [":translate.choices.$0.message.content", ":chat.swappedContext.person1.name"],
    },
  },
};

export const main = async () => {
  const result = await graphDataTestRunner<{ messages: { role: string; content: string }[] }>(
    __filename,
    graph_data,
    {
      groqAgent,
      shiftAgent,
      nestedAgent,
      openAIAgent,
      propertyFilterAgent,
      stringTemplateAgent,
      textInputAgent,
    },
    () => {},
    false,
  );
  if (result?.chat) {
    console.log("Complete", result.chat["messages"].length);
  }
};

if (process.argv[1] === __filename) {
  main();
}


node.js のコードだと思いますが、実行環境はセットアップしてますか？不明点を明確にしてもらえると回答がつきやすくなると思います。

一から自分で書いたのではなく、何かを参考にしたのであればコードが掲載されていたところに実行方法も合わせて書いてあったりしませんか？それらの情報も記載があると良いと思います。

そのコードはgraphaiパッケージにあるサンプルinterview_jp.tsであってますでしょうか？
このパッケージを使い方はREADME.mdにあります。まず、この文章を読んで、このパッケージが何か、どうやってインストールするのか、どうやって使うのかを理解する必要があります。それを理解してはじめてinterview_jp.tsが何をしているのかがわかります。interview_jp.tsはあくまでサンプルであるため、この内容を参考に自分がしたいことをコードを書けば良いとなります。
interview_jp.ts自体を実行したいという場合、単独でそのまま実行出来るようにはできていません。packages/samples/のディレクトリにあるサンプル集の一つとして実行出来るようになっています。ですので、このディレクトリをまるごとローカルにコピーして、package.jsonにあるパッケージをインストールして、適切なAPIキーが書かれた.envファイルを用意して、npm run sample src/llm/interview_jp.tsとすれば実行出来ると思われますが、2024年5月26日時点の最新のレポジトリでは必要なモジュールのパッケージ化がされていないなどの理由でうまくいきませんでした。
どうしても、動かしたいというのであれば、ちょっと古い0.4.3を試して見てください。こちらはsapmlesにサンプルがあり、トップで一緒に管理されています。たとえば、次のような方法でできます。(Node.jsとYarnが必要です。インストール方法は自分で調べるか、わからなければ新たなな質問として聞いてください。)
curl -OL https://github.com/receptron/graphai/archive/refs/tags/0.4.3.tar.gz
tar xzf 0.4.3.tar.gz
cd graphai-0.4.3
yarn install
echo OPENAI_API_KEY=sk-proj-... > .env
npm run sample samples/llm/interview_jp.ts

OPENAI_API_KEYはGPT-4oにアクセス可能なライセンスを持つアカウントで作成したOpenAIとAPIキーを入れてください。(私はライセンスを持っていないので、最終的な動作確認まではできていません。)
